# xml Deserialize a list of objects containing a list of objects in c#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a list of objects that in turn contain lists of other object. What I've got is the following.
The actual deserializing is done by the framework in a ApiContoller httpPost request. The endpoint looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MethodCall([FromBody] XmlEntries entries)
    { 
     .... 
    }
```

The XmlEntries class looks like this:

```
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class XmlEntries
{
    [XmlArrayItem("XmlEntry")]
    public List<XmlEntry> XmlEntries{ get; set; }

    public XmlEntries()
    {
        XmlEntries = new List<XmlEntry>();
    }

    public XmlEntries(IEnumerable<XmlEntry> entries)
    {
        XmlEntries= entries.ToList();
    }
}
```

The XmlEntry class look like this:

```
public class XmlEntry
{
    [XmlArrayItem("XmlSubEntry")]
    public List<XmlSubEntry> XmlSubEntries{ get; set; }
}
```

and the XmlSubEntry looks like this.

```
public class XmlSubEntry
{
    string AttributeOne{ get; set; }
    int? AttributeTwo{ get; set; }
}
```

I've been using fiddler to send the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <XmlEntries>
    <XmlEntry>
      <XmlSubEntries>
        <XmlSubEntry>
          <AttributeOne>P</AttributeOne>
          <AttributeTwo>8</AttributeTwo>
        </XmlSubEntry>
        <XmlSubEntry>
          <AttributeOne>S</AttributeOne>
          <AttributeTwo>26</AttributeTwo>
        </XmlSubEntry>
      </XmlSubEntries>
    </XmlEntry>
  </XmlEntries>
</Root>
```

My problem is that the attributes of XmlSubEntry never gets correctly serialized. When i debug the MethodCall in apiController entries will be a list containing 1 XmlEntry with XmlSubEntries being a list of 2 XmlSubEntry, but the attributes (AttributeOne and AttributeTwo) are always null.

I have tried annotating the classes In all ways I can thing of but I still won't get the attributes to serialize correctry.

Is there any XML-ninjas around that can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best tip I can give you is to do this in reverse - add some data and serialise it to XML, see what it looks like. That will usually point to where you're wrong.

In this case, however, you're *very* close. The only issue you have is that you can't serialise private properties, so make them public:

```
public class XmlSubEntry
{
    public string AttributeOne { get; set; }
    public int? AttributeTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was making it more complicated than I needed to. The solution was hiding i plain sight. :)